# Fileupload is not working with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, file-upload, requirejs

I am having a problem when loading fileupload whilst using requirejs. The error that it gives me is:

```
TypeError: this._on is not a function
```

and I guess it is because fileupload requires jquery.ui.widget to be loaded too.
So I tried importing the lib, but I can't seem to make this right. Can anyone help me how to load it properly?

this is the code:

```
    require.config({
paths: {
    'jQuery': 'lib/jquery-1.10.2.min',
    'jQuery-ui': 'lib/jquery-ui-1.10.3', 
    'jQuery-ui-widget' : 'jquery.ui.widget',
    'bootstrap': 'lib/bootstrap.min',
    'jquery-iframe': 'jquery.iframe-transport',
    'fileupload': 'jquery.fileupload',
},
shim: {
    'jQuery': {
        exports: '$'
    },
    'jQuery-ui': {
        deps: ['jQuery'],
        exports: '$'
    },
    'jQuery-ui-widget': {
        deps: ['jQuery', 'jQuery-ui-widget']
    },
    'bootstrap': {
        deps: ['jQuery', 'jQuery-ui']
    },
    'fileupload': {
        deps: ['jQuery', 'jQuery-ui', 'jquery-iframe']
    }
},
// only for development purporses:
urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime()
```

});
require(['jQuery', 'jQuery-ui', 'bootstrap', 'layout', 'menu', 'modal', 'table', 'form', 'fileupload'], function ($, jqueryUi, _bootstrap, layout, menu, modal, table, form, fileupload) {

```
$(document).ready(function () {...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your configuration:

1. jQuery does not need a shim, and using a shim where none is needed can cause troubles.
2. jQuery hardcodes its module name as `jquery` (all lowercase) so you cannot refer to it under the name `jQuery`. Well, you *could* use a [`map`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map) config to map `jQuery` to `jquery` but you currently do not have such `map` in your configuration. I would recommend using `jquery` across the board, which is the current practice in just about every project I see that uses RequireJS and jQuery.

I also recommend using [`enforceDefine: true`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-enforceDefine) in your configuration so that RequireJS provides better diagnosis of module loading failures.